# stuck with simple select statement to return single rows

Tags: sql-server-2008, select

Have a very simple select statement that I need to perform and for some reason can not wrap my head around it even though i have done these before. I have a table as per the below :

```
CustomerNo  Code    FA  DateDUE
8625475   SAFETY    A   05/02/2014
8625475   REVIEW    A   18/06/2014
8625475   CHECK     C   18/06/2014
8885742   REVIEW    A   23/01/2014
8885742   TEST      B   23/01/2014
```

UPDATED Question to be clearer : I need to select data where the FA code is an A and the only code with an A is a REVIEW, So in the above the select statement it would return only one Customer Number (8885742) - Hope this is clearer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want all records of a customer:

```
select * from your_table
where customerNo in
(
  select customerno 
  from your_table
  where FA = 'A'
  group by customerno
  having sum(case when code <> 'REVIEW' then 1 else 0 end) = 0
)
```

If you only need the `customerno`

```
  select customerno 
  from your_table
  where FA = 'A'
  group by customerno
  having sum(case when code <> 'REVIEW' then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

### [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b6590/1)

Comment: sorry thats my bad, there's another flag i need to add into the equation, the FA code can change depending on the Code set, so there could be FA code of A,B,C,D i need to look only at the code A's as well. _

Comment: What does that mean? Does FA have tob e always A?

Comment: Yeah i'd just worked the same out, thanks a lot for the help. greatly appreciated.